# Objeto para um array javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um objeto com os seguintes valores:

```
let sel = { 
    "1": { "id_turma": 485, "codigo_turma": "1112A - 41", "ano_ciclo": 14 }, 
    "2": { "id_turma": 486, "codigo_turma": "1112B - 27", "ano_ciclo": 18 }, 
    "3": { "id_turma": 487, "codigo_turma": "1112C - 24", "ano_ciclo": 14 }
}
```

Eu preciso transformar em um array assim:

```
valor['1112A'] => 14
valor['1112B'] => 18
valor['1112C'] => 14
```

Eu tentei assim:

```
let val = []

sel.forEach(function(ix) {
    if(ix.value) {
        val[ix.value] = ix.ano_ciclo
    }
})
```

Não está dando certo

Comment: E os números 41, 27 e 24 em `codigo_turma`? Devem ser ignorados?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss São apenas informações. Eles devem são ignorados

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para usar o `forEach`, seu objeto precisar ser um array `[]`, como é um objeto de objetos, você pode usar o [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) para isso:

```js
let sel = { 
    "1": { "id_turma": 485, "codigo_turma": "1112A - 41", "ano_ciclo": 14 }, 
    "2": { "id_turma": 486, "codigo_turma": "1112B - 27", "ano_ciclo": 18 }, 
    "3": { "id_turma": 487, "codigo_turma": "1112C - 24", "ano_ciclo": 14 }
}

let  valor = [];

Object.entries(sel).forEach(([o, v]) => {
    valor[v.codigo_turma.substring(0,5)] = v.ano_ciclo;
});

console.log(valor["1112A"]);
console.log(valor["1112B"]);
console.log(valor["1112C"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma é utilizando o map, veja como ficaria:

```js
let sel = { 
    "1": { "id_turma": 485, "codigo_turma": "1112A - 41", "ano_ciclo": 14 }, 
    "2": { "id_turma": 486, "codigo_turma": "1112B - 27", "ano_ciclo": 18 }, 
    "3": { "id_turma": 487, "codigo_turma": "1112C - 24", "ano_ciclo": 14 }
}

sel = Object.keys(sel).map(key =>
    ({ [sel[key].codigo_turma.split('-')[0].trim()]: sel[key].ano_ciclo })
);

console.log(sel);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let sel = {
  "1": {
    "id_turma": 485,
    "codigo_turma": "1112A - 41",
    "ano_ciclo": 14
  },
  "2": {
    "id_turma": 486,
    "codigo_turma": "1112B - 27",
    "ano_ciclo": 18
  },
  "3": {
    "id_turma": 487,
    "codigo_turma": "1112C - 24",
    "ano_ciclo": 14
  }
};

let val = [];

Object.values(sel).forEach(function(ix) {
  val[ix.codigo_turma.split(' ')[0]] = ix.ano_ciclo
});

console.log('val[\'1112A\']:', val['1112A']);
console.log('val[\'1112B\']:', val['1112B']);
console.log('val[\'1112C\']:', val['1112C']);
```